# Quick way to sync now

Tags: sync

Is there a quick way to do a *sync now*?

The long way is to go into Settings, then Accounts, then tap the account name then tap the three dot menu and choose *Sync now*, but this is a bit long winded. It would be nice if there was a *one tap* option to sync now direct from the launcher home page.

I ask because I use Keep for transferring text between my PC and the phone and *vice versa*, but Keep is sometimes a bit slow about syncing changes to notes and I need to do a *sync now* to make it transfer the changes immediately.

If it makes a difference I'm using a Nexus 5 with Marshmallow.

Comment: I don't have Android 6 so can't verify, however, in Android 5.0 there is an activity named `com.android.settings.Settings$AccountSyncSettingsActivity` that does the job of the Sync I presume. See if [QuickShortcutMaker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sika524.android.quickshortcut) works in Android 6. If it does, use it to find the Sync activity under Settings app and make a shortcut from there.

Comment: @Firelord: thanks. Creating a shortcut to Settings$AccountSyncSettingsActivity doesn't do anything, but creating a shortcut to Accounts does work and that's a few less taps. Do you want to post your comment as an answer? If no-one can do any better I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note:** *This answer is not tested on Android Marshmallow*.

---

In Android 5.0, one can create shortcut for sync using the activity `com.android.settings.Settings.$AccountSyncSettingsActivity` (since I've only one account in the whole device, the activity *may* do nothing for multiple accounts without passing specific parameters).

Anyhow, attempt to create the shortcut for sync using an app like [QuickShortcutMaker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sika524.android.quickshortcut) or [Activity Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.szalkowski.activitylauncher) or even an automation tool like [tasker](/questions/tagged/tasker).

[As per OP](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/128721/quick-way-to-sync-now?noredirect=1#comment159990_128721), it has  come to my notice that sync shortcut does nothing in Marshmallow. OP also mentioned that the activity for Accounts works well. So for the time being, settle with Accounts activity (`com.android.settings.Settings$AccountSettingsActivity`). The shortcut can be created using the aforesaid apps.